# Error creating relationship with FOSUserBundle and custom entity with easy-extends

Tags: symfony, orm, fosuserbundle, relation, sonata

I followed [this documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html) in sonata, step by step and it worked.
Then I added a new entity and tried to generate a relation many to many to user entity, and when I validate it return this error

```
$ bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

Mapping
-------

 [FAIL] The entity-class AppBundle\Entity\Business mapping is invalid:
 * The association AppBundle\Entity\Business#user refers to the owning side field Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#business which does not exist.


Database
--------


 [OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

This are my two entities

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

```
/**
 * Business
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="business")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BusinessRepository")
 */
class Business
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="BusinessName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $businessName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fantasyName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fantasyName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cuit", type="string", length=13)
     */
    private $cuit;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\BankAccountType", inversedBy="business")
     */
    private $bankAccountType;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="business")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = true;
```

And this

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;


use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 *
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends
 *
 * References:
 * @link http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Business", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="business_user")
     */
    private $business;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->business = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share your whole entity class please

Comment: that's the whole entity without getters and setters

Comment: But it lakes the constructor in your Business entity

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for the same thing and it works.

```
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="wizai\WMC\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="customRoles", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}


class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="wizai\WMC\UserBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="users", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $customRoles;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

if its still not possible, can you first run a migration or a force update ?

Commands

1. bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
2. bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

if not, then try.

3. bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete

Comment: There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:migrations" namespace. The update --force works but the validate not

Comment: is there a middle table created for user_business in your database ?